# How to concatenate conditions with & to filter a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to generalize a function to use it in different dataframes:

```py
def existence(x):
    return df[df.isin([x]).any(1)]
```

I need to generalize it to a function that accept a variable number of parameters, like:

```py
existence([[x1],[x2],...,[xn]]):
    return df[df.isin([x1]).any(1) & df.isin([x2]).any(1) & ... & df.isin([xn]).any(1)]
```

isin() can accept a list as a parameter, but compares with an "or" between each element of the list, showing any row that contains even an element of that list. That's why I need an "&" between the conditions, I've been trying to do something like:

```py
cond = [['A'],['B']]     ##isin only accept list items not str
df_diag[np.logical_and.reduce(df_diag.isin(cond).any(1))]
```

but he's not behaving as I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension for loop by values in `cond`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('Abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('BaabbA')
})

print (df)
   A  B  E  F
0  A  4  5  B
1  b  5  3  a
2  c  4  6  a
3  d  5  9  b
4  e  5  2  b
5  f  4  4  A

cond = [['A'],['B']]
m = np.logical_and.reduce([df.isin(x).any(1) for x in cond])
print (m)
[ True False False False False False]

m = (pd.concat([df.isin(x).any(1) for x in cond], axis=1)).all(axis=1)
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

If use sets in pure python, it working nice, only necessry change condition to `['A','B']`:

```
m = df.apply(lambda x: set(['A','B']).issubset(x),axis=1)
```

Comment: KeyError: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000019B7207E228>

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2:** As an alternative to [jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56286519/565489)), you could use:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':list('Abcdef'),
    'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
    'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
    'F':list('BaaBbA')
})

def existence(df,columns,cond):
    return df[df[columns].apply(lambda x: 
                np.isin(np.array(cond).astype(str), x.astype(str).tolist()).all()
            ,axis=1)]

print(existence(df,df.columns,['A','B']))
print(existence(df,df.columns,[ 4,'a']))    # note the different types
```

yields:

```
   A  B  E  F
0  A  4  5  B

   A  B  E  F
2  c  4  6  a
```

Which however requires explicitly enforcing a dtype via `.astype(str)`, since this solution iterates over the DataFrame *row-wise*, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56288089/565489).