# Unexpected behaviour from applying np.isin() on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

While working [on an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56286723/565489), I stumbled upon an unexpected behaviour:

Consider the following DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':list('AAcdef'),
    'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
    'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
    'F':list('BaaBbA')
})
print(df)
```

```
   A  B  E  F
0  A  4  5  B  #<— row contains 'A' and 5
1  A  5  3  a  #<— row contains 'A' and 5
2  c  4  6  a
3  d  5  9  B
4  e  5  2  b
5  f  4  4  A
```

If we try to find all columns that contain `['A', 5]`, we can use [jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56286519/565489):

```py
cond = [['A'],[5]]
print( np.logical_and.reduce([df.isin(x).any(1) for x in cond]) )
```

which (correctly) yields: `[ True  True False False False False]`

If we however use:

```py
cond = [['A'],[5]]
print( df.apply(lambda x: np.isin([cond],[x]).all(),axis=1) )
```

this yields:

```py
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Closer inspection of the second attempt reveals that:

- `np.isin(['A',5],df.loc[0])` **"wrongly"** yields `array([ True, False])`, likely due to `numpy` infering a dtype `<U1`, and consequently `5!='5'`
- `np.isin(['A',5],['A',4,5,'B'])` **"correctly"** yields `array([ True,  True])`, which means we can (and *should*) use `df.loc[0].values.tolist()` in the `.apply()` method above

**The question, simplified:**

Why do I *need* to specify `x.values.tolist()` in one case, and can directly use `x` in the other?

```py
print( np.logical_and.reduce([df.isin(x).any(1) for x in cond]) )
print( df.apply(lambda x: np.isin([cond],x.values.tolist()).all(),axis=1 ) )
```

**Edit:**

Even worse is what happens if we search for `[4,5]`:

```py
cond = [[4],[5]]
## this returns False for row 0
print( df.apply(lambda x: np.isin([cond],x.values.tolist() ).all() ,axis=1) )
## this returns True for row 0
print( df.apply(lambda x: np.isin([cond],x.values ).all() ,axis=1) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in DataFrame are mixed numeric with integer solumns, so if loop by rows get `Series` with mixing types, so numpy coerce the to `strings`.

Possible solution is convert to array and then to `string` values in `cond`:

```
cond = [[4],[5]]

print(df.apply(lambda x: np.isin(np.array(cond).astype(str), x.values.tolist()).all(),axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Unfortunately for general solution (if possible only numeric columns) need convert both - `cond` and `Series`:

```
f = lambda x: np.isin(np.array(cond).astype(str), x.astype(str).tolist()).all()
print (df.apply(f, axis=1))
```

Or all data:

```
f = lambda x: np.isin(np.array(cond).astype(str), x.tolist()).all()
print (df.astype(str).apply(f, axis=1))
```

If use sets in pure python, it working nice:

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: set([4,5]).issubset(x),axis=1) )
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool

print(df.apply(lambda x: set(['A',5]).issubset(x),axis=1) )
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: So I guess the key is that your `[df.isin(x).any(1) for x in cond]`- solution iterates over every row item in every column, hence it infers the "correct" `dtype` for every DataFrame element, thus ensuring a valid comparison, whereas my attempt iterates row-wise, hence "upgrading" `int` to `string`, correct?

Comment: @Asmus - There is used [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), so hard question like it working internally. But in list comprehension is iterate each value in `cond`.

Comment: Ah, if you just run `print([(x,df.loc[0].isin(x)) for x in cond])` you can see it creates booleans for each element, which is why you needed to `logical_and.reduce` it. That's why your code worked better than mine. By the way, your `set()` solution is *so much nicer*, you should really consider putting it into [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56286519/565489)

Comment: why did you remove your nice `set()` solution, anything wrong with it?

Comment: @Asmus - I replace it like you want :)

Comment: @Asmus - now is back :)

Answer (score 0):

Because

1. [`df.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) applies to `pd.Series` and [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) does not.
2. [`pd.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) returns a `pd.Series`.
3. To transform `pd.Series` to array-like, your `x.values.tolist()` should work.

Comment: Interestingly, the `.values.tolist()` method fails if `cond = [[4],[5]]`, i.e. both are integer, see **Edit** above.